# Suggestion required for Normalization

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, database-normalization

I want to store virustotal.com results in my Database. but I am having some problem in normalization. suppose I am having the following general table

```
AntivirusName    FileID    DetectedID    DetectedDate
AVG               1         abc            --/--/--
Kaspersky         1         xyz            --/--/--
Norton            1         xxx            --/--/--
```

Now if a file is detected by 40 antivirus, then there are 40 entries against it in database. so how can I remove these repeatation, Kindly guide me

Comment: They're not repeats - they are valid information. You can tell from this info what AV's didn't pick up the file. You may wish to look into the `DISTINCT` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that there can be more than one scan per day (`DetectedDate`), which will find one or more virus signatures (`DetectedID`) in one or more files (designated by `FileID`) as detected by multiple products (`AntivirusName`). So, in the current structure, you can have duplicate values in all columns and thus duplicate rows. This means you need to add an `id` column to provide a unique key. You could then replace the `AntivirusName` with an `AntivirusNameId` which is a FK to another table with `AntivirusNameId` and `AntivirusName` columns. It's unclear from your question if you would have to do the same with `FileID` and `DetectedID`, but I think not.

So, your tables would be:

```
create table av_name as (
  AntivirusNameId int,    -- PK
  AntivirusName VARCHAR(50)
);
create table av_scan as (
  id int,                 -- PK
  AntivirusNameId int,    -- FK
  FileId int,
  DetectedID  CHAR(3),
  DetectedDate DATE
);
```

Comment: here DetectedID is basically a name with which an antivirus identifies a malicious file e.g. trojan.123

Comment: But `FileID` isn't anything to do with `DetectedID`, right?